# Trying to keep facets visible even when the terms restrict facets

Tags: search

I believe the setting I am looking for is minimum facet count, so that I can set it to 0.

I'm going based on this:

https://drupal.org/node/1669600#comment-6190924

I don't have search API installed, however I do have Apache Solr installed.

When I'm searching for something, say tech, whenever there are results that don't have that keyword, the facets are disappearing - the client doesn't want the facets to disappear.

I tried to disable this disappearance in the template.php above, but it didn't work.

How do I keep facets visible in Apache Solr even when there are 0 results?

Answer (score 0):

> How do I keep facets visible in Apache Solr even when there are 0 results?

As I know, it's not possible. You can make separate query for display facets, but they cannot be displayed if solr return no data.